# How to prevent menu from wrapping

Tags: css

I have been building a menu bar for my site, except each time I try adjusting my browser width for testing, my menu just becomes a list crowded on the left side. I tried adding in `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`except it doesn't work. Any ideas?

screenshot of error: 
[image]

HTML:

```
 <div id="header" class="row">  
     <ul class="nav-bar">
                <div class="large-2 columns"><li data-slide="1"><a href="">home</a></li></div>                      
                <div class="large-3 columns"><li data-slide="2"><a href="">portfolio</a></li></div>
                <div class="large-2 columns"><li class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></li></div>
                <div class="large-2 columns"><li data-slide="3"><a href="">about</a></li></div>
                <div class="large-3 columns"><li data-slide="4"><a href="">contact</a></li></div>
            </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    /*position: relative;*/
    top: 0;
}
div#header ul{
    height: 128px;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div#header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #003264;  
    text-align: center;
    height: 128px;
    line-height: 128px;
    /*padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;*/
    font-size: 36px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Site: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/

Comment: is this only an issue on non desktop-sized devices?

Comment: This screenshot was on my desktop, I just took the browser and shrunk down the width and this is what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because once screen width has decreased sufficiently, Foundation uses its alternate (small-screen) CSS. Since you have no "small" width (only a "large" width), Foundation by default will expand your columns to a width of 100%.

This can be addressed using just Foundation's predefined classes, no CSS modification required. For your `.nav-bar` children, simply specify a "small" width as well.

```
<ul class="nav-bar">
    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns"><li data-slide="1"><a href="">home</a></li></div>                      
    <div class="large-3 small-3 columns"><li data-slide="2"><a href="">portfolio</a></li></div>
    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns"><li class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></li></div>
    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns"><li data-slide="3"><a href="">about</a></li></div>
    <div class="large-3 small-3 columns"><li data-slide="4"><a href="">contact</a></li></div>
</ul>
```

This seems to solve the problem for me. If this wasn't what you were looking for, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the `div.large-*` tags inside of the `li` tags.
2. Specify a min-width (or width) for `#header ul`